# Docker official images vs custom images

Tags: image, docker

I am trying to figure out the importance of custom images. Do you have to create and use custom images for your environment, or you can get all the images you need from Docker official images?

Thanks,

Comment: This question is too broad for this forum. The short answer is yes, the long answer depends on your needs. Try to elaborate more and we can try to provide you with a meaningful answer.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply Yaron. Based on your experience, do you think 50% of the people end up creating custom images or is it more like 5% ?

Comment: I'd say every person that uses docker professionaly created a custom image.

Comment: This is good. Thank you.

Comment: Have you ever used Packer to create custom images? If yes, what are your thoughts on that? Thanks!

Comment: Packer is not for docker images, but for VMs. Docker can be thought of as the same thing as Packer but for containers. My thoughts on Packer were that they're very good.

Comment: I see. When would you use Packer vs custom image?

Comment: It's a completely different use case. Packer is used to create VM images, and docker is used to create container images. I suggest reading up about the difference between the two before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I am using both - a custom image made by me and a ready image from the docker hub. I am using the custom image for my web application and for the database I can easily use an image of postgresql or mysql and just link them both using a docker-compose.yml. So to answer your question, you will normally end up using both.

Comment: Good info. Thank you.